# Get position of mouse in form VB6

Tags: vb6, mousemove

In a program I'm writing, I need the position of the mouse absolute to the left upper corner of the form.
I'm using this code:

```
Private Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    Debug.Print "x: " & X & " - y: " & Y

End Sub
```

When I use this code, the upper left corner has coordinates 0,0. But the problem is that the values are 15 times too big when I move inside the form.

So that's why I used:

```
Private Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    Debug.Print "x: " & X / 15 & " - y: " & Y / 15

End Sub
```

This gives the correct coordinates, but why do I need to devide this by 15?
I'm not sure if this code will be compatible on other systems.

Comment: For me, coordinates are the amount of pixels from the left upper corner. When it gives me 15000 for example, I know it's not right, because it should be 1000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445516%28v=VS.60%29.aspx). The X and Y values returned correspond to the "ScaleHeight, ScaleWidth, ScaleLeft, and ScaleTop properties of the object."

Therefore looking at the documentation for [ScaleHeight, ScaleWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445663%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and for [ScaleLeft, ScaleTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445665%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), it is clear that you can dictate how the X and Y coordinates are determined. You are not limited to Twips or Pixels, but can use whatever numbering system you dictate.

Here's a quote from the ScaleHeight, ScaleWidth page:

> For example, the statement ScaleHeight = 100 changes the units of
>   measure of the actual interior height of the form. Instead of the
>   height being n current units (twips, pixels, ...), the height will be
>   100 user-defined units. Therefore, a distance of 50 units is half the
>   height/width of the object, and a distance of 101 units will be off
>   the object by 1 unit.

In this regard to assure your results match your expectation, you can tell the form exactly how many user-defined units it contains.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working by changing the scalemode to pixels.

Comment: +1 If the results differ from your expectation, check the documentation to see whether your expectation is at fault.

Answer (score 2):

The units are in [`Twips`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip) (runtime conversion factor: `screen.TwipsPerPixelX` and `Y`).
You can also change the forms `ScaleMode` to use `Pixel`s.